# Ausgestorbene Wörter im österreichischen (Standard-)Deutsch

Tags: austrian, archaism

Gibt es irgendeine Liste dazu? Ich kenne nur Werke/Websites entweder zu ausgestorbenen Wörtern im bundesdeutschen Deutsch oder zum heutigen österreichischen Deutsch. Ich habe gerade mal schnell gegoogelt, gefunden habe ich aber nur einen Artikel, der das Thema anreißt: https://kurier.at/buzz/woerter-die-wir-vermissen/59.613.311 So richtig schön wären aber Wörter, die heute kaum einer mehr kennt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich kenne keine wirklich seriöse Quelle zu diesem Thema, kann aber trotzdem, wenn auch mit Vorbehalt, die Facebook-Gruppe [Erinnerungsraum für fast ausgestorbene Worte](https://www.facebook.com/groups/184695161570864/) empfehlen. Das ist eine geschlossene Gruppe, man muss also um Aufnahme ansuchen.

Die Empfehlung kommt mit Vorbehalt, weil die meisten Begriffe, die dort gepostet werden, keine hochdeutschen Wörter sind, sondern Dialektwörter aus dem Raum Wien. In der [Metropolregion Wien](https://www.stadtregionen.at/wien/bev%C3%B6lkerung) leben mit 2,5 Millionen Menschen fast 30 % der rund 8,8 Millionen Österreicher, aber trotzdem ist der Wiener Dialekt meilenweit davon entfernt, mit österreichischem Hochdeutsch ident zu sein.

Der Anteil der wirklich vom Aussterben bedrohten Wörter ist dort ebenfalls nicht sonderlich hoch, ich würde sagen: unter 50%. Aber immerhin kann man dort viele alte Wörter finden, die in Österreich verwendet wurden.

---

Viele alte Wörter, die in Österreich verwendet wurden, kann man auch auf [Ostarrichi.org](http://www.ostarrichi.org) finden, aber auch dort sind meiner Schätzung nach mehr als 95% aller eingetragenen Wörter Dialektwörter, hier aber aus allen Regionen Österreichs. Das liegt aber daran, dass diese Seite ausdrücklich den österreichischen Dialekten gewidmet ist. Vokabel aus dem österreichischen Hochdeutsch sind dort aber trotzdem nicht verboten, daher findet man auch sie.

---

Zudem findet man in beiden Quellen auch sehr viele Begriffe, die ich »Spaß-Synonyme« nennen möchte. Das sind lustig wirkende Begriffe, die viele schon mal auf ähnlichen Seiten gelesen habe, und die man daher gerne wieder auf solchen Webseiten postet, die im Alltag tatsächlich aber kaum verwendet werden. Damit meine ich z.B.

> A Eitrige mit an Bugl
>   (Eine Eitrige mit einem Buckel)

womit eine Käsekrainer (entfernt verwandt mit der deutschen Currywurst, aber ohne Curry, dafür mit Käse) gemeint ist, die mit einem Scherzel (Randstück eines Brotlaibes) serviert wird. Tasächlich sind »Käsekrainer« und »Scherzel« hochdeutsche österreichische Wörter. Ich habe aber im Alltag noch nie gehört, dass jemand an einem Würstelstand wirklich »a Eitrige mit an Bugl« bestellt hätte.

Wie ich gerade bemerkt habe, hat sich der Begriff »Eitrige« als Synonym für [Käsekrainer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4sekrainer) sogar auf Wikipedia verirrt. Aber wie schon gesagt: Daran ist eher schuld, dass dieser Begriff lustig und ungewöhnlich ist. Tatsächlich verwendet wird er im Alltag so gut wie gar nicht, was im Abschnitt [Verwendung im Wiener Dialekt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4sekrainer#Verwendung_im_Wiener_Dialekt) aber auch korrekt so dargestellt wird.

Comment: Vielen Dank, das ist schon mal etwas!

Comment: +1 schon für Laib :)